# Skip an extraction in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

How can I skip the first extraction in Imacros?

This is the script:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SECTION ATTR=ID:listing-H1151777 EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.substring(140,230);;")
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
```

I want when I saved it to CSV file to get only VAR1 data.

Comment: Let the 3rd line of your macro look like so: `SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try POS=2 instead of POS=1. This will begin the extraction at the second instance instead

http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG

Answer (score 0):

option 1: change ADD to SET in the 3rd line

option 2: if you need to run multiple times use a new variable VAR2 instead of EXTRACT in the 3rd line to keep the string